# Flask app can't find static files on AWS ECR + Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

I have flask app with next structure:

```
templates/
  dashboard.html
static/
  css/
    styles.css
  js/
    main.js
Dockerfile
app.py
```

In `app.py` I just have one endpoint to serve main page.

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/home")
def dashboard():
    return render_template('dashboard.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

dashboard.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Dashboard</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">
   </head>
   <body>...</body>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/main.js')}}"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

The app is hosted on AWS ECR+Fargate ( I am not the person who did devops side).

The app works, but static files (js and css) are not loaded, error 404. What could I miss?

Comment: What does app.py do? I imagine it's using jinja for generating the html?

Comment: @Paolo exactly :)

Comment: Can you share app.py? You should make your question a minimal, reproducible example

Comment: @Paolo updated initial post

Comment: I just tested this and it seems to work fine locally; does it work for you locally too?

Comment: @Paolo locally and in local docker container, it works like a charm.